# Simple counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

There’s a problem for which I get two different answers depending on the choice of approach. I’d like to know why one of the answers is wrong.

Problem: If I use a random number generator that can generate the numbers in the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} 19 times, what is the probability that I generate each number at least once?

Approach 1: Use indicator random variables I1 through I5 (1 if selected at least once and 0 otherwise), apply inclusion-exclusion, do some algebra, get an answer of 93%.

Approach 2: For the denominator, treat this as counting the ways that we can put 19 distinguishable balls in 5 urns. For the numerator, treat this as the number of ways we can put 14 distinguishable balls in 5 urns. This gives a number less than 40%.

My hunch is that the second method is wrong as the events being counted are not equal probability events. Is that correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first approach is correct.

Comment: Thanks, what’s the error in approach 2?

Comment: For the second approach, why would putting 14 balls in 5 urns be relevant here? Also, an easy way to at least sanity check theoretical results like these would be a quick simulation. A single line of R like `mean(replicate(1e5,length(table(sample(1:5,19,TRUE)))==5))` runs a few seconds and gives `0.92844`.

Comment: Thanks, the rationale is to put a ball in each urn, and then count the number of ways to put 19-5 = 14 balls in 5 urns. Also, thanks for the quick sim - I do know the second answer is incorrect; I’m interested in understanding what the error in that approach is. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, but *why* should we care about putting 14 balls in 5 urns? What does that have to do with the original problem? The point is that there is no connection between the two, so this does not lead to the correct answer.

Comment: Well, the way I thought about the numerator is: if you want to get each number at least once, you need to “put a single ball” into each urn once. This then gives the number of ways you can  get non-zero selections from each member of the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

Comment: Try a smaller version of the problem, such as generating numbers in $\{1,2\}$ three times.  That will enable you to enumerate all possibilities and check your reasoning.